# Solr search with group by and having clause for reporting

Tags: mysql, solr, lucene, reporting, solr4

I have around 20 millions of documents added in solr with respect to below table structure.

id | mobile | amount | retailer | timestamp

Now I need those mobile number whose have recharged more than x times ?

When I need these result in mysql I fire below query "*select mobile,count(mobile) as total from table group by mobile having total > x*"

How to I achieve same result in solr ?  I have tried "select?q=*%3A*&wt=json&indent=true&group=true&group.field=mobile" but its gives me all records of mobile[grouped] with numcount but how to I add limit to the numcount [*that is having clause in mysql*]

I have recently started using solr for reporting purpose.**So am I in right direction to use solr for these kind of queries or are there any other tools/technology/methods to deal with these kind of reporting queries because mysql hangs with 20m records**. Also in future my data can increase upto 100m

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with facetting:

*select?q=*%3A*&wt=json&facet=true&facet.field=mobile&facet.mincount=100*

then look for *facet_counts* in the response.

This should work fine including with very large indexes.